# What does the following JavaScript function do and what can I use it for?

Tags: javascript

What does the following code do and what is the use of it?

**JavaScript**

```
function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){
    if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)
    {
        var s = strx.split("<"); 
        for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){ 
            if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){ 
                s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length); 
            } 
        } 
        strx =  s.join(""); 
    }
    chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2; 
    while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++; 
    strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1); 
    return strx+'...';
}
```

Comment: don't you think that the identifier is more than enough?

Comment: What is its name?  What does it look like it does?  Have you followed the code step by step?  Where are you getting confused?

Comment: Thank you for your help, the question has been answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It parses HTML and removes tags in a manner that is really pretty loose. It can fail in certain circumstances. For example if there's a `>` inside an attribute value, or if there's a `<` in the text without a tag name directly after it, it'll mess up the result.

It also optionally truncates the text returned. The `while` loop ensures that the truncated text happens at a space character.

So if you pass it a string of HTML, aside from the problems I noted above, it'll give you back the string without the tags. And if you pass it a number as the second argument, it'll limit the length to that number (again, except that it'll add to it to avoid chopping a word in half).